# Как получить элементы в библиотеке jsoup

Tags: android-studio, jsoup

По средствам библиотеки *Jsoup* получаю текст с сайта. Мне нужны определенные строки, но сайт дает дополнительные, по совпадению имени класса.

Помогите разобраться. Меня интересуют первые несколько строк `buil-item`. Как убрать дополнительные `extended_item` которые ниже?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Замените картинку текстом.

Answer (score 0):

Для исключения элементов используйте псевдоселектор `:not(selector)` или метод `Elements.not(String)`. Подробная информация в [документации](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html).